# How to copy the national language characters into the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a **language_lookup** table like below,

[image]

And I have a **language_details** table like below,

[image]

My objective is to copy the regional_names from language_lookup table and insert it into the language_table. But when I try to do that, all non-english characters are converted into ? Question marks.

The current output which I am getting is,

[image]

The query I am using,

```
update ld
set ld.regional_name = ll.regional_name
from language_details ld
inner join language_lookup ll on ll.language = ld.language
```

Is there any way to convey SQL server that ll.regional_name is national language, something similar to,

```
set ld.regional_name = [N] ll.regional_name
```

**Note:** I have set the datatype as NVARCHAR(50) for both columns.

Comment: Seems like when you've `INSERT`ed/`UPDATE`d the data you used a `varchar`, not an `nvarchar`. It doesn't matter if the column is an `nvarchar`, if you use a (literal) `varchar` for the value the data is already lost.

Comment: All the 4 columns are NVARCHAR(50), Even while inserting or updating it is the same.

Comment: Again, the data type of the column doesn't matter if you provided a `varchar` to start with. `'I am not a nvarchar'` would lose any characters outside of the code page of the collation you are using (note there likely aren't any in that `varchar` literal).

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a604d56048dec73a92a403ea57c804f8). Double-check your assumptions. (For example, whatever client you're using to retrieve these values might be doing it wrong, or the table might have a trigger defined on it that uses the wrong data type.)

Comment: Is there an update trigger on the table "language_details"?

Comment: No update trigger. In the DB setup example by @JeroenMostert the issue is not reproducible, but in my local setup, it is still reproducible, I wonder why.

Comment: When dealing with `nchar` and `nvarchar` values get in the habit of using National character literals so as to avoid the loss of Unicode characters that don't exist in your database's default collation. e.g.: compare the outputs from `select N'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ', 'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ'`

Comment: What does `select * from language_lookup` show? Also what is the collation of the columns in each table?

Comment: select * from language_lookup would give the first image as output, 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL

Comment: The columns in *both* tables have that collation? Are there any other `cast` `collate` `convert` or other calculations done in your `update` query? What client are you using to retrieve the data, is it SSMS? Are you *sure* there are no triggers on the table?

Comment: Yes, both columns in both tables have the same collation. Yes, in the actual problem I have multiple columns so I am just checking for is not null case. Yea I am testing it through SSMS. There is no triggers.

Comment: Can you share the execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. No-one can repro this, so looks interesting